# No space in etal

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am using natbib for bibliography with the following configuration.

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{authordate3}
\setcitestyle{authoryear, aysep{" "}}
```

But, somehow during citations after authorname etal. comes together rather than et al.? Could someone provide a hack to it? Thanks!!

Edit 1: I used master's thesis template for harvard from overleaf. Here is the [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv).

Edit 2: Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_ZUUa41t80KRaHCGNeLIhYe0MgoYUMxy) to thesis template not requiring signing to overleaf.

Edit 3: I had added the above 3 lines of natbib and the bibliographystyle is changed to authordate3 (etal. comes in italic font now).

Comment: Is the bib style available on the internet?

Comment: @gigi, I used template for master's thesis for harvard from overleaf. Here is the link - https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv.

Comment: Can you include it in your question? I don't have overleaf account

Comment: @gigi the template is not a single file but comes as a list of folders. How could I include it in the question?

Comment: Are you saying that you're getting `etal.` instead of `et al.`? Please advise.

Comment: Your write-up is somewhat confusing: In your code snippet, you indicate that you use the `authordate3` bibliography style; however, in the linked template file, the `apalike2` bibliography style is in use. Please clarify which bibliography style is actually in use. (Hint: if "et al" is typeset in italics, it's probably the `authordate3` style.)

Comment: @Mico Exactly, I am getting etal. instead of et al. authordate3 seems to override apalike2 bibliography style. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mico, did you find any way to solve this etal. no space issue? I removed "authordate3" style but there was no change in etal. spacing though it is no longer italic.

Comment: @RaunakLohiya - Please see the brief answer I posted a minute ago. The upshot is that I cannot reproduce the output you say you're getting if I utilize only the (rather scant) information you've provided so far.

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I can only surmise that you either have corrupted versions of the `apalike2` and `authordate3` bibliography styles on your system or have code somewhere in the document that modifies the hard-coded string "et al." to "etal.".

For sure, the following minimalist working example produces no "etal" output. On my system (MacTeX2019), both bibliography styles have hard-coded "et al." in the files.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc, author="A and B and C", year=3001, title="Thoughts"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}% or: {authordate3}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```